# How to to render category view for my custom collection?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am attempting to render a category view and feed that view a custom collection. The layout is rendering and the data is being passed from URL to collection but I cannot get the category to push the collection to the layout.

```
 require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'CategoryController.php';
 class Coder_Catalog_RecipesController  extends Mage_Catalog_CategoryController
{
    $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design')->applyDesign();
//        $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($category);

        $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $update->addHandle('default');
                    $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
        $this->loadLayoutUpdates();

        $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();

        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    $params=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $flavor=$params[0];
    if(empty($params)){
        return $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }else{ 
        $product = Mage::getModel ('catalog/product') 
            ->getCollection () 
            ->addAttributeToFilter ('url_key', $flavor)  
            ->getFirstItem (); //only 1 result 
        if(!$product->getId()){
            echo 'fail';
        }
        $groupedParentsIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_link')
           ->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED);
    } 
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you gave, going this in a block will be better.

1. Create a custom module
2. Copy the category view you want into another .phtml file,
3. Create a block, add your category collection logic in a method
4. call the method in the .pthml to get collection
5. In the xml set the template of the block to the new category.pthml file.